# Multiple inline variables in "IN" clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a single table in which all the data is stored row wise.

```
key      name   field   value
11       sam    state   1
11       fred   state   1
21       sam    state   3
21       fred   state   1
11       sam    dist    1
11       fred   dist    1
21       sam    dist    1
21       fred   dist    1
```

I need a query to fetch the number of `"name" having dist = 1 with  state = 1` .

Something on following lines..
    select count (value) 
    from table
    where  field = 'dist' 
    and value = 1 
    and **key , name**  in (select **key ,name**  from table where field = 'state' and value =1)

In above example I expect answer as  "3"   ( sam with key = 21 is not eligible).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select count (value) 
from table a
where  field = 'dist' 
and value = 1 
and exists
(
  select 1 from table n where field = 'state' and value =1
  and a.key = b.key 
  and a.name = b.name
)
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked on podiluska's solution .

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(distinct yourtable.name)
from yourtable
inner join
(
    select key, name from yourtable
    where field='dist' and value = 1
) dist1
    on yourtable.key = dist1.key 
    and yourtable.name = dist1.name
where field='state' and value = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a join:

```
select count(distinct key, name) from table t1
inner join table t2
  on t2.key = t1.key and t2.name = t1.name and t2.field = 'state' and t2.value = 1
where t1.field = 'dist' and t1.value = 1
```

Comment: Thank you Guffa . Worked on podiluska's solution that helped me. It was same as yours. Thank you once again.

Comment: @user1606540: Well, this joins directly on the table and not on a subquery.